# unknown option charset tarantool + lua

Tags: lua, charset, tarantool

Пытаюсь запустить проект на, который содержит в себе кодировку, но происходит ошибка.

```
tarantoolctl:551 E> Start failed: /dewt/app/.rocks/share/tarantool/http/utils.lua:4: Unknown option 'charset'
```

в проекте есть файлы, которые содержат параметр этот:

```
app/web.lua:        resp.headers["content-type"] = "text/html; charset=utf-8"
app/web.lua:     "application/json; charset=utf8"
app/web.lua:        "text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

Может ли быть проблема в версиях или каких-то модулях, которых не добавила или нескомпилировала?

```
tarantool -v

Tarantool 2.2.2-0-g0a577ff

Target: Linux-x86_64-RelWithDebInfo

Build options: cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DENABLE_BACKTRACE=ON

Compiler: /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin/cc /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin/c++

C_FLAGS:-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -fexceptions -funwind-tables -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-stack-protector -fno-common -fopenmp -msse2 -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-format-truncation -fno-gnu89-inline -Wno-cast-function-type

CXX_FLAGS:-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -fexceptions -funwind-tables -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-stack-protector -fno-common -fopenmp -msse2 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-cast-function-type
```

```
lua -v


Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
```

Comment: можно глянуть файлик app/web.lua?

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогла замена /dewt/app/web.lua на последнюю версию из репозитория. Видимо сборка устарела